# Where to get models for TransferLearning based on topics

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, transfer-learning

Suppose you're searching for a pretrained model for e.g. human gender recognition, or age estimation (Transfer Learning).
So, you'd want a net that is trained on, ideally, human faces and not on stuff like the ImageNet dataset.

I know that there are two big starting points for the search:

- Keras applications
- TensorHub

Now, the best I've found is to use the search tool of the TensorHub website, like [here](https://tfhub.dev/s?module-type=image-augmentation,image-classification,image-feature-vector,image-generator,image-object-detection,image-others,image-style-transfer,image-rnn-agent&q=human).

That gives me some models trained on the CelebA-HQ dataset, which is something I was searching for.

But, it didn't give any results for e.g. the keywords "sport", "food" or "gun".

---

So, what is a good way to find pretrained models for a desired "topic"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to find a model for each topic at a single place.

The general strategy could be searching in GitHub with the relevant tags `["tensorflow", "sport"]`.

You can generally find many models on model-zoo websites: https://modelzoo.co/

This is also useful: https://github.com/tensorflow/models

If you need code (probably with pre-trained weights): paperswithcode.com is a good place to search.